# Consulta MySQL com LIKE

Tags: mysql

Fiz a query abaixo para retornar todos os registros que contém a palavra 'Juscelino' na tabela de usuários, a palavra 'Juscelino' se repete 3 vezes, a query busca em 3 campos diferentes, o que não é obrigado conter em todos os campos a palavra para retornar o resultado.

Executando a query no phpMyAdmin o resultado é zero, sem erros, deveria retornar os 3 registros da tabela com os dados relacionados, mas não retorna nada.

```
SELECT 
    `user_email`,
    `user_username`,
    `user_nome`,
    `user_sobrenome`,
    `user_token` 
FROM 
    `usuario` 
WHERE 
    `user_nome` 
LIKE '
    %Juscelino%'
OR 
    `user_sobrenome` 
LIKE 
    '%Juscelino%'
OR 
    `user_username` 
LIKE 
    '%Juscelino%'
ORDER BY 
    `user_nome` ASC,
    `user_sobrenome` ASC
```

A tabela tem o seu collation definido para 'utf8_general_ci', e é uma tabela MyISAM.

Comment: Como disse o Ronaldo, tem uma quebra de linha dentro das aspas do LIKE

Comment: @Bacco,  qual o motivo de estar fora do escopo se é uma dificuldade genuína e real?

Comment: A mensagem está no quadro amarelo. Visto que já foi encontrada a solução e é apenas um erro de digitação, então não é um caso que justifique a postagem ficar como referência futura para outros visitantes (que, afinal, é a filosofia do site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE 
    user_nome
LIKE ' --    <---- o erro está aqui
    %Juscelino%'
```

Comment: Alterei e funcionou, falha nossa, o retorno não dava erro mesmo assim. abs

Answer (score -1):

Tenta usar ilike para desconsiderar o as letras maiúsculas:

```
 SELECT 
`user_email`,
`user_username`,
`user_nome`,
`user_sobrenome`,
`user_token` 
FROM 
  `usuario` 
WHERE 
  `user_nome` 
ILIKE '
   %Juscelino%'
OR 
  `user_sobrenome` 
ILIKE 
'%Juscelino%'
OR 
`user_username` 
ILIKE 
'%Juscelino%'
ORDER BY 
`user_nome` ASC,
`user_sobrenome` ASC
```